# collapseOnSelect in react-bootstrap navbars with react-router-dom NavLinks

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-router-dom

I'm making a website where I'm using react-router-dom's NavLink components to prevent rerenders for a single page application experience.

As I am trying to make the site responsive, I have been trying to make the responsive navbar from react-bootstrap collapse after selecting a NavLink, but the collapseOnSelect behaviour doesn't seem to work for anything other than the Nav.Link components that come with react-bootstrap.

Other solutions have recommended passing down props to the nav (navExpanded:true) with manual toggle functions etc, but this seems to still force a rerender due to the state change. The main reason I want to avoid this is because I have made transitions between pages using react-transitions-group.

```
<Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="md" variant="dark">
    <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="/"><Logo/></Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="Navs ml-auto">
                <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/about">ABOUT</NavLink>
                <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/portfolio">PORTFOLIO</NavLink>
                <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/contact">CONTACT</NavLink>
            </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Container>
</Navbar>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem and the maintainer has closed three github issues without resolution. All advice he has given me has failed. I really dont think its working... see: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/4081

Comment: Found the solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 15):

I have the same problem, i use the Nav.Link from 'react-bootstrap' as Link from 'react-router-dom', don't forget to add the href attribut.
In this example all links except pizzas link collapse the nav bar. 
Hope it's Help You.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
import NavBrand from './NavBrand/NavBrand';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Navigation = ({ brand }) => {
    return (
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand='sm' bg='dark' variant='dark' fixed='top'>
            <NavBrand text={brand.text} />
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='responsive-navbar-nav' />
            <Navbar.Collapse id='responsive-navbar-nav'>
                <Nav className='mr-auto'>
                    <Nav.Link as={Link} to='/assiettes' href='/assiettes'>
                        ASSIETTES
                    </Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link as={Link} to='/pizzas'>
                        PIZZAS
                    </Nav.Link>

                    <Nav.Link as={Link} to='/sandwichs' href='/sandwichs'>
                        SANDWICHS
                    </Nav.Link>

                    <Nav.Link as={Link} to='/tacos' href='/tacos'>
                        TACOS
                    </Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    );
};

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: Found the solution, see my answer.

Comment: Awesome - this even worked for me using `import { Link } from "gatsby-plugin-intl";`

Comment: If you have a 'home' link with the href of '/' you may find that its not set to active on page load. You can use the NavLink from react-router-dom instead of Link and apply an activeClassName='active' prop to fix this issue. No need for react-router-bootstrap which only supports react-router v4.

Comment: u had solution if using anchor link? because when i use HasLink to solve the issue, the collapseOnSelect won't work..

Answer (score 4):

Found an answer that worked for me on a similar post. Adding `EventKey="1"`, `EventKey="2"`, etc. to the `NavLink` items was all it needed. I am using `react-router` and never needed to switch it to `react-router-bootstrap`.

[This answer helped me.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56485081/13850303)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

You need to use [react-router-bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap) instead of `react-router` to make it work.

Example:

```
import { Navbar, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import React from "react";
import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";

class Navigation extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect>
          <Navbar.Brand/>
          <Navbar.Toggle/>
          <Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav className="mr-auto">
              <LinkContainer to="/page1/">
                <Nav.Link>Create</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              <LinkContainer to="/page2/">
                <Nav.Link>Open Disputes</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use these settings and it will work.

```
import { Nav, Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useHistory, Link } from "react-router-dom";

     <Nav.Link // Use Nav.Link from react-bootstrap

        as={Link}  // Use as prop and set to Link from react-router-dom  
 
        eventKey="0" // add different eventKey to all Nav.link

        to="/profile"
      >
        Profile
      </Nav.Link>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping to find! Seems ridiculous to throw in another task-specific package to do what what is already supported by the ones already used.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/anonymous-order" eventKey={"4"}>
    A. Order
</Nav.Link>
```

trying adding event key as i added above worked for me